# If Post type use sidebar ('tree')

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

Not the best with code but im looking for a snippet which will remove the default sidebar and use a dynamic one instead for a certain post type

```
if ( is_singular( 'knowledge' ) ) {

    </div> <!-- #left-area -->
    <?php Remove_sidebar();?>

        <?php dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar2'); ?>
    </div>

}
```

any help?

Comment: you can do that with a custom template for this C.P.T., look that : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 1):

Copy the template you want to change to a template  called `single-knowledge.php`. Then edit that to include your preferred sidebar instead of the "default" one. Whenever `is_singular('knowledge')` is true, that template will be used. Make WordPress do the heavy lifting!!